# How to flip an image that uses a source rectangle in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm drawing an image using Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint). I want to flip the image for left and right movement but I cant use a matrix with this method. I can rotate using canvas.rotate but thats no use for flipping, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using scale + translate. The following code flips left-to-right:

```
canvas.scale(-1, 1);
canvas.translate(-canvas.getWidth(), 0);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
canvas.setMatrix(null);
```

Without translate your bitmap will be drawn with negative coordinates - outside the left edge of screen.